# LXC multiple unprivileged containers UID & GID questions

Tags: lxc

I created multiple unprivileged LXC containers successfully. However they all have the same UID and GID as follow:

```
ls -l /.local/share/lxc
total 12
drwxrwx--- 3 100000 js 4096 Jan 21 20:20 js-hp-lxc-001
drwxrwx--- 3 100000 js 4096 Jan 21 20:22 js-hp-lxc-002
drwxrwx--- 3 100000 js 4096 Jan 21 20:22 js-hp-lxc-003
```

Can/Should they have different UID? If so, how can I do it?

My concern is about security between containers.

Comment: Any info on that? I was thinking the same thing... Atm I am modifying the mapping (added 65536*10 u/gids) but I have to do this manually since the default settings always use `0 100000 65536` + I have to `sudo chown` the `rootfs` and containing folder.

Comment: It seems there is no definite answer for that. I myself is using script to create those config files.

Comment: Cheers man for the fast response! I am thinking of doing the same... or wait to upgrade to ubuntu 15 and test with `LXD` ...

Comment: I am using 16.04 and the latest lxc 2.0 package, seems very smooth. If you are interested I can upload my scripts to github. But they are very much tailored to my current config and not very flexible yet.